# Will a baked animation be consistent over many animations?

Tags: animation, physics

That is to say, if I crash and restart my PNG render from file 137, will my frame 136 and 137 be smooth, even if I have complex physics and turbulence set up?

Right now I am troubleshooting a bug with my animation, and I want to rule this out as a root cause

Comment: If your physics and all simulations are baked, then the animation will be consistent